# Spark - Not able to read CSV file

Tags: csv, apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

I am using databricks to read csv file. when I tried to read CSV file with `inferSchema` it showed me following error.

```
 Unable to infer schema for CSV. It must be specified manually.
```

And when I am supplying schema. It's not showing any error. However, dataframe is empty.

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType, DateType
schema = StructType([ 
    StructField("hdfs_path",StringType(),True), 
    StructField("operation",StringType(),True), 
    StructField("date",StringType(),True),
  StructField("_corrupt_record",StringType(),True)
  
  ])

legacy_hdfs_data = spark.read \
.format("csv")\
.schema(schema)\
.option("header","true")\
.load("abfss://sss@xxx.blob.core.windows.net/legacy_hdfs_event/")
```

**sampleData**

```
col1,col2,col3\naaa,bbb,ccc\nxxx,yyy,zzz
```

**Update:**

- I have tried different options like `multiLine`, `linSep` as `\n`. However, nothing is working.
- I just moved the file to `bdfs` and it works.

Comment: can you share your sample data?

Comment: @avikm seems like the issue with file, it has `LF` however when I tried to see the file in databricks. Rather showing new lines it shows `\n`

Answer (score 0):

If your csv files contains multiple lines in any of the cell then you will get such error. Just adding one more option while reading csv- `option("multiLine", true)` should solve the issue.